# Determine file system of a copied file from file timestamp log

Tags: filesystems, timestamp

I've got a log file (.csv) that lists folders and files and various dates of every record on a hard drive, including: Std Info Creation date,   Std Info Modification date, Std Info Access date, Std Info Entry date, FN Info Creation date, FN Info Modification date, FN Info Access date, FN Info Entry date. A particular text file was copied onto the drive and I can find the record with the dates etc. How would I go about if I want to find out what file system this file was copied from? Would there be another record just before or after the file's record that would give a clue? Should I be looking for a record that has the same timestamp of one of those dates maybe?

Comment: Give more info about the file-systems of source and target, operating systems, and how the copy is done.

Comment: hi - the only info I have is the log file itself. it has a file name column with entries like this: "/Windows/WinSxS/amd64_microsoft-windows-exfat_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_3ae76b6b8255f93e" and "/Users/Dave/NTUSER.DAT{8ebe95f7-3dcb-11e8-a9d9-7cfe90913f50}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms".  Do these type of entries say anything about the file-system a file is copied from?